# Firestore - getting data from a reference like 'collectionName/{id}' and iterating over the resulting list

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get all data from 'anunturi_postate' reference list.
Variable 'post_data' pushed to the list looks ok in the loop, but outside the loop, the list it's empty.

I added an image from the console and the firestore emulator for a better view of what I'm trying to do.

[image]

```
// db = firebase.firestore()
async function postedByUser(){

    let query = await db.collection("users").doc($current_user.uid).get()

    let user_posts = []
    // anunturi_postate it's a field name which holds an array
    await query.data().anunturi_postate.forEach(async (doc) => {
        let post = await db.doc(doc.path).get()
        let post_data = await post.data() 
        console.log(post_data) // data looks ok
        user_posts.push(post_data)
    })

    console.log("user_posts:", user_posts) // here it's empty
    return user_posts
}

let user_posts 
postedByUser().then(data => {
    user_posts = data
})

// here it's empty
console.log("After func call: ", user_posts)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

async/await does not work inside a forEach loop in the way you expect. The loop does not return a promise that you can await, and will not finish before moving on to the following code.  Use a for loop instead.  Also, you can use each reference as if it was a DocumentReference object.

```
    let user_posts = []
    const array = query.data().anunturi_postate
    for (let ref of array) {
        let post = await ref.get()
        let post_data = await post.data() 
        console.log(post_data) // ok
        user_posts.push(post_data)
    })

    console.log("user_posts:", user_posts)
```