# FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() cannot be called with an empty path

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, svelte-3

I am getting a list of id's from users collection then when I am trying to get by id data from another collection anunturi this error:

> FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() cannot be called with an empty path

```
<script>
import { db } from "../Utils/fire.js"
import { current_user } from "../Utils/auth.js"
import Room from "./Room.svelte"

async function interestedForUser(){
    let query = await db.collection("users").doc($current_user.uid).get()
    const listingsIds = await query.data().anunturi_interesat 
    console.log(listingsIds) //ok
    let anunturi = []
    for (let id of listingsIds) {
        console.log(id, typeof(id)) // ok
        let anunt = await db.collection("anunturi").doc(id).get() // nok
        let anunt_data = await anunt.data() 
        if (anunt_data) {
            anunturi.push({...anunt_data, listingId:id})
        } 
    }
    return anunturi
}

</script>

{#await interestedForUser()}
    <p class="text-center mt-12">Se incarca...</p>
{:then listings}
    {console.log("In template:", listings, listings.length)} //ok (but why?)
    {#if listings.length > 0} // this doesn't get rendered..
        {#each listings as camera }
            <Room {camera}/>
        {/each}
    {:else}
        <p class="text-center mt-12">Nu ai postat nici un anunt</p>
    {/if}
{:catch error}
    <p style="color: red">{error.message}</p>
{/await}
```

[image: console error]

**UPDATE:**

The issue was in the `<Room {camera}/>` component. A child of `Room` component had a firestore reference undefined.

Answer (score 2):

I've the same type of problem in Next JS when I try to fetch data of a specific id from Firebase.

Try this if you're facing issue in next js.

```js
import React, { useState ,useEffect} from "react";
import StudentsWithID from "../../Componenets/Navbar/Form/StudentsWithID";
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

const StudentWithId = ({sid}) => {
  const [student,setStudent] =useState();
  /*
  const router = useRouter();
  const { sid } = router.query; 
  
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
  
  I try to get id of student with these lines. but It doesn't when i build the project (npm run build)
  ?: file name is [sid].js || It is not working in [id].js

  */
  useEffect(()=>{
    const loadStudent=async ()=>{
   try{
      const result= await firebase.firestore().collection("students").doc(String(""+sid.sid)).get()
      const my_student=result.data()
      if(my_student){
      setStudent(my_student)
      console.log(my_student)
    }else{
      console.log("Stundent not found")
    }
  }catch(err){
console.log("-----------------StudentError------------------")
console.log(err.message);
  }}
loadStudent()
  },[])
 
  return (
    <div>
      <StudentsWithID props={student}/>
    </div>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps({query,params}) {
  //todo: when I try to get id in server it works perfectly.
const sid=query||params
  return{
    props:{
      sid:sid
    }
  }

}

export default StudentWithId;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that this bit of code has a problem:

```
doc(String(id))
```

If `id` is already a string (we can't tell from what you show here), then just pass it directly:

```
doc(id)
```

If it is a number, and you want to convert it to a string:

```
doc(id.toString())
```

If it is something else, then you'll have to be more specific about how you want to convert it to the string of the document ID you want Firestore to use.

Comment: The id is auto-generated by firestore. I get the same error with or without `String(id)` (I saw in another SO post that id's must be strings). It's weird because for `collection("users").doc($current_user.uid)` it works.

Comment: I added all the code, removed `String(id)`. Getting data by ref works in a identical component on which you helped me [(so post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65144783/firestore-getting-data-from-a-reference-like-collectionname-id-and-iterati). Probably it's something svelte related.

Comment: try to make a check on `listingsIds` before the for loop in `interestedForUser`. like `if listingsIds` then run the loop otherwise return an empty array

Comment: I wrapped the for loop in a `if (listingsIds.length > 0)`, but I got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

the error happens when you pass a variable into the doc(), which is null, undefined, or a non-string value.

So, first convert the variable to a string by toString()

Then, put the update code inside an if block like this:

```js
if (varName) {
  //update code here
}
```

this makes sure that the update part only runs if the variable's value is not null or undefined

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just forgot to pass a string value as the second argument of the `collection` function. I am using it in a reusable custom hook where `collectionName` is the argument to be used as the collection name, and when I called the hook I forgot to pass an argument.

Hook:

```
export const useCollection = (collectionName) => {
  let ref = collection(db, collectionName)
  ...
}
```

Hook Call:

```
  const { documents: books } = useCollection("books")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `doc()` function only accepts `string` value. So, If you want to use `string` variable, you should put backticks around it with `$` sign.

Like this:

```
export const UserOrders = (props) => {

  const userId = props.userId

  const getOrderDetails = () => {
    db.collection('users').doc(`${userId}`).collection('orders').get().then((snap) => {
      if(snap){
          const getOrder =  snap.docs.map((doc) => ({
            ...doc.data()
          }))
        console.log(getOrder)
      }
    }).catch(err=>{toast.error(err)}) 
  }

 window.onload = getOrderDetails()
```

Here `userId` is a variable. It is used in `doc()` function as `string`.