# React FireBase | Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Function doc() cannot be called with an empty path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-context

Im trying to make a ItemDetail page using FireStore with ReactJS.
The issue is in the momento im trying to call to doc and getting the ID from firebase item.
In the console web i have the next error
 `Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Function doc() cannot be called with an empty path.`
What i looked in other forums or StackOverflow, thats can maybe fixed with id.toString(), but this is not the case.

This is the code

FireStore.js (Not full code because ApiKey, and etc...)

```
const db = getFirestore(app);

export async function getProduct(id) {
  const productsCollectionRef = collection(db, "productos");
    const docRef = doc(productsCollectionRef, id)

  const docSnapshot = await getDoc(docRef);

  return docSnapshot.data()
}

export default db;
```

ItemListContainer ( This gives a preview of the product and the access to the detail )

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { ItemList } from "./ItemList";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { getAllProducts } from '../../../services/firestore';

export const ItemListContainer = ({ greeting }) => {
  let { categoriaID } = useParams();
  
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [isloading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

 useEffect(() => {
  getAllProducts().then( data => {
    console.log("item list cont", data)
    setIsLoading(false);
    setItems(data);
  })
  .catch( (errorMsg) => {
    console.log(errorMsg);
  })
 }, 
 [categoriaID]
 );

  return isloading? (
    <h2>Loading...</h2>
  ) : (
    <>
      <h3 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>{greeting}</h3>
      <ItemList items={items} />
      
    </>
  );
};
```

This is the Detail Container with the calls

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { ItemDetail } from "./ItemDetail";

import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { getProduct } from "../../../services/firestore";

export const ItemDetailContainer = () => {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
 

  const { id } = useParams();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)


 useEffect(() => {
  setLoading(true)
  getProduct(id)
  .then ( (itemsPromise) => {
    setProduct(itemsPromise);
    
  })

  .finally(() => {
    setLoading(false);
  })
 },
 [id]
 );
 

  return (
    <>
    <section>
      { loading ? <h1> Cargando ....</h1>  :  <ItemDetail item={product} />}
    </section>
    </>
  )
};
```

ItemDetail (This is the call and Map to ItemDetailContainer)

```
import React from "react";
import ItemCount from "../card/ItemCount";
import "../../css/card/Item.css";
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import { useContext, useState} from 'react';
import {CartContext} from '../../../context/CartContext'

export const ItemDetail = ({
  id,
  nombre,
  categoria,
  imagenID,
  precio,
  descripcion,
  imagenALT,
  stock,

}) => {

const { addToCart } = useContext(CartContext);
const [purchasedCompleted, setPurchaseCompleted] = useState(false);
const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0);

  
  const onAdd = (quantity) => {
    setQuantity(quantity)
    setPurchaseCompleted(true);
    const productToAdd = {
      id,
      nombre,
      categoria,
      imagenID,
      precio,
      descripcion,
      imagenALT,
      stock
    
    }
    addToCart(productToAdd, quantity);
  }


 
  return (
    <div className="text-center border">
      <img src={imagenID} alt={`${id}-${imagenALT}`} />
      <section>
        <h1>Producto: {JSON.stringify(nombre)}</h1>
        <p>ID: {id}</p>
        <p>Descripcion: {descripcion}</p>
        <p>Categoria: {categoria}</p>
       s <h2>Precio: ${precio}</h2>

        
          {quantity ? (
            <div>
             <Link to="/cartpage" className="btn btn-success"> Terminar mi compra</Link>
             <Link to="/catalogo" className="btn btn-danger"> Seguir comprando </Link>
             </div>
          ) : (
            <ItemCount stock={stock} initial="1" onAdd={onAdd} />
          ) 
}
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is the image of ItemListContainer ( When you click in a card, this go to ItemDetail.JS )

[image: ItemListContainer]

This is the image of ItemDetail (The undefined of the img is on porpouse):

[image: ItemDetail.js]

This is an example of the collection and doc in firebase:

[image: doc and collection example]

Note: the Urls are okay, in the case of the image go to: product/og7JpLMr1vDT0GMw7w23 <-- This is the ID

I want to clarify, im a rookie on React, the dev world and my native language is spanish, this can explain the errors on the text

Comment: Is the issue with `collection(db, "productos")` or is it on `doc(productsCollectionRef, id)`? What is the "empty path"?

Comment: the "doc" is the "empty path" the collection is defined using const productsCollectionRef. That you can see it in the firebase.js (first code), but i dunno why the itemdetail gaves undefined/unknow to the props(nombre, precio, stock, etc...) of the products

Comment: So the issue is the second one, and `docRef` is the "empty path"?

Comment: Yeah, in the console of dev tools thats say the doc is the empty path. :/.

Comment: the objetive is the itemdetail shows the data of the doc that you entered using firebaae, in a simple explanation, when you click a card that goes to details of the card and this need to show the properties, like price, name (precio and nombre), and after was added to a context and cartpage

Comment: Check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65290888/firebaseerror-function-collectionreference-doc-cannot-be-called-with-an-empty

Comment: Yep, i tryed this before making this post, but no results.